# Can you return integers with comma spacing from SOQL Aggregate statements?

Tags: apex, soql

Is it possible to have commas in a SOQL statement that returns a large integer?

For example, if SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM Opportunity was 700000 could that be returned anywhere as 700,000?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From SOQL, no, it will always return the raw data (a Decimal value). Besides, commas, periods, and spaces mean different things to different regions of the world. For example, all of these are representations of seven-hundred-thousand: "700,000.00" "700 000,000" "700.000,000". You wouldn't want to display the wrong symbols, which may be misinterpreted. You should simply allow the system to format the values for you according to the user's locale.

You can use a wrapper class to get the correct value, such as this:

```
public class FormattedNumber {
    Decimal internalValue;
    FormattedNumber(Decimal value) {
        internalValue = value;
    }
    public override String toString() {
        return internalValue == null? null: internalValue.format();
    }
}
```

You can then get a list of values for proper rendering on screen:

```
public FormattedNumber getQuarterlyTotal() {
    return new FormattedNumber(
        (Decimal)[SELECT SUM(Amount) amt FROM Opportunity WHERE CloseDate = THIS_QUARTER][0].get('amt')
    );
}
```

(Note: code written for brevity. Be sure to include proper error checking.)

Comment: Fantastic answer! That makes a lot of sense! Thanks again, sfdcfox :)

Comment: Mind blowing. You never cease to amaze me @sfdcfox. You truly rock !!